# ActionScript - getPixel() Coords on BitmapData with Transformation Matrix?

Tags: actionscript-3, matrix, bitmap, pixel, transformation

i've filled a circle shape with the bitmap data of a bitmap asset.

i need to rotate the circle from the center, so i added the bitmap to the center of the circle and used a matrix transformation to shift the bitmapdata upward and leftward so it appears centered.

now i'm trying to read the bitmap data with `getPixel()` but the return value is off since it is returning the untransformed position of the bitmap data instead of the visible transformed bitmapdata.

```
Bitmap(Sprite(evt.currentTarget).getChildAt(0)).bitmapData.getPixel(evt.localX, evt.localY)
```

how can i get an accurate reading of the pixel data from a bitmap with a matrix transformation?

---

updated with code.  assume the redCircleData in my example is more colorful and something worth retrieving pixel data.

```
var redCircleData:Sprite = new Sprite();
redCircleData.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 1.0);
redCircleData.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 100);
redCircleData.graphics.endFill();

var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.tx = redCircleData.width / 2;
matrix.ty = redCircleData.height / 2;

var myBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(redCircleData.width, redCircleData.height, true, 0x00FFFFFF);
myBitmapData.draw(redCircleData, matrix);

var theBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(myBitmapData, PixelSnapping.AUTO, true);
theBitmap.x -= matrix.tx;
theBitmap.y -= matrix.ty;

addChild(theBitmap);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Matrix class gives you some very handy functions to deal with your problem:

Matrix.invert();

Matrix.transformPoint();

Get the inverse of your matrix (invert a copy of it) and then transform your Point(e.localX,e.localY) with it. Use the transformed point coords as your arguments to getPixel(). BitmapData is just a block of RGB or RGBA pixels in memory, where (0,0) is the upper left. You need the to work backward through the transform you use to display it to find the pixel of the bitmap that is under your mouse. That's what the inverted matrix does for you.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/geom/Matrix.html

Comment: I need to wrap my brain around Matrix a bit better - I had to do something very similar a few months ago and while I got the matrix transforms working I had no idea how to find (0, 0) in a meaningful way. What I ended up doing was creating a wrapper, adding the transformed image to the wrapper and then drawing the wrapper - which is obviously going to be incredibly slow, comparatively.

Comment: The important thing to remember (for me anyways) is that matrix multiplication is not commutative (AB is not the same as BA), so when you have more than one transformation matrix applied to something sequentially, you have to undo the transformations in the reverse order you applied them to get back to where you started, or (equivalently) multiply them together in that order before inverting.

Comment: after reading the docs i'm not sure if this will work in my situation.  incase i'm not quite following you, some sample code would be appreciated.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't get a good feel for the problem from your sample. Even imagining that your actual bitmap is more interesting and less radially symmetric, I don't understand how you're using the matrix in your actual code. You don't need a matrix to simply translate a Bitmap inside a DisplayObjectContainer, I was assuming that in your actual code, you were using it for rotation and possibly scaling as well, in which case the inverse of your transformation matrix would be a quick way to do the reverse transformation from local coordinates back to the BitmapData's coordinate space.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if what you're trying to do is possible (I've never tried it, at least, and I'm under the impression that you can't really apply a transformation to a `BitmapData` object, but I might be wrong). However, you could create a new `BitmapData` with a snapshot of the region you're interested in and read the pixels from this new object. This way you could easily achieve what you want.

Comment: it's unfortunate that it doesn't seem possible to be able to assign a registration point to bitmapdata objects.  if that was possible it would all be so much easier.  i've update my question with some more code showing my process of emulating a center registered bitmap and bitmapdata.  it's also counterintuitive that while the bitmapdata is passed to the bitmap, it's coords are static as it doesn't move along with the bitmap if the bitmap is moved - which is the current problem.